# How to prevent a web browser from following redirects in a specific website?

Tags: browser, javascript, redirection, userscripts

I am trying to block myself from using *Google Search Console* by bringing myself back to *Google Search*, due to addictive behavior with *Google Search Console**.

The following JavaScript code [works from web browser console here](https://search.google.com/search-console/about), but not from a userscript:

```javascript
window.setInterval( () => {
    const urlPatternToBlock = [
        'https://search.google.com/'
    ];

    for (const element of urlPatternToBlock) {
        if (window.location.href.includes(urlPatternToBlock)) {
        window.open("https://google.com/", "_self");
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

The non-working userscript is:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New Userscript
// @run-at      document-start
// @match       *
// ==/UserScript==

window.setInterval( () => {
    const urlPatternToBlock = [
        'https://search.google.com/'
    ];

    for (const element of urlPatternToBlock) {
        if (window.location.href.includes(urlPatternToBlock)) {
        window.open("https://google.com/", "_self");
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

I figure that the reason this code only works from console but not from the suerscript is because of some 301 redirect or some other redirect.
Let along, the URL stays the **same** in the *URL field* of the web browser so if there is a redirect here it must be elusive.

How to prevent a web browser from following redirects in a specific website?
This specific website doesn't have anything to do with any sensitive information such as payment details, passwords or anything else so in general blocking its redirects is not a problem.

### Update

The following code with a single value via a modified `@match` command works, but it still doesn't solve the original problem I have, which deals with an array of values.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google_single_value
// @run-at      document-start
// @match       https://search.google.com/search-console/*
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.location.href.includes('https://search.google.com')) {
    window.open("https://google.com/", "_self");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userscript doesn't work because of invalid `match`. This is a proper one if you want it to affect all websites:

```
// @match *://*/*
```

And then your script works fine. Tampermonkey basically follows URL match patterns used by browsers, see e.g. [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/) for more details about the `[scheme]://[host]/[path]` pattern.

But it could be just simplified to:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google_single_value
// @run-at      document-start
// @match       https://search.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.replace("https://google.com")
```

if you want to redirect the pattern that you showed.

`window.location.replace` is recommended in terms of redirection BTW as it doesn't add a history record.

Comment: Changing `// @match       *` **to** `// @match       *://*/*` seems to have solved the problem. Thank you.